# MS Access vba to detect if another Office app is open

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have several routines in my Access project that automatically create, open and close either Word documents or Excel spreadsheets.  Some functions also automatically send e-mail via Outlook.
I have started to get end/debug messages on simple statements relating to opening and closing (quitting) instances of these apps.
I think I need to determine if these apps are already open or not when performing a routine?  This would be irrespective of which files are open in them.  My searching seems only to be able to find how to determine if a particular file is open or not.
Thank you

I haven't found any solutions to try.

Comment: Have a look at [GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function).  There's an example at the bottom for detecting if Excel is open or not.  Can be easily updated to look for Word our Outlook.  `Set MyVar = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` will return a reference to Excel if it's open, or will return error 429 - ActiveX component can't create object.

Answer (score 0):

See code fragments for running Word and Open Word file.

Check, is Word running

```
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 and Err.Number = 429 Then '429 - ActiveX component can't create object
       WordWasNotRunning = True
       Err.Clear    ' Clear Err object 
       Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
       objWord.Visible = fVisible
       WrdStatus = cWrdStartedWithMe
    ElseIf Err.Number=0 then
       'no error - Word started before
       WordWasNotRunning = False
       WrdStatus = cWrdStartedBefore
    Else ' throw error
       msgbox Err.Description
    End If
    on error goto 0
```

Check is file opened in Word. pFileName - our target file

```
    With objWord.Documents ' list of opened files
       For ii = 1 To .Count
          fn = .Item(ii).FullName
          If fn = pFileName Then
             Set myWorkBook = .Item(ii)
             FileIsOpened = True
             WB_OpenStatus = cWBOpenedBeforeMe
             Exit For
          End If
        Next ii
     End With
```

If file not already opened, then Open

```
        On Error Resume Next
                                                           'links  'readonly
        Set myWorkBook = objWord.Documents.Open(pFileName, False, forReadOnly)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            If Err.Number = 5174 Then ' File not found
                Err.Clear
                msgbox "File " & pFileName & " not found"
                OpenWorkBook = -21
                GoTo Exit_OpenWorkBook
            else ' other error
                msgbox "Error opening " & pFileName & ":" & Err.Description
                OpenWorkBook = -31
                GoTo Exit_OpenWorkBook
            End If
            Err.Clear
        Else
             FileIsOpened = True
             WB_OpenStatus = cWBOpenedWithMe
        End If
```

Close Word

```
        If Not myWorkBook.Saved Then 
           ' do something - save or not 
        End If
        If WB_OpenStatus = cWBOpenedWithMe Then
           myWorkBook.Close (False)
        End If
        If WrdStatus = cWrdStartedWithMe then
           objWord.Quit
        End If
```

Manipulation with Excel is similar.

Comment: You can save the error properties in variables to use in your code. After `Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")` insert `errNum = Err.Number`, `errDesc = Err.Description` then `On Error GoTo 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity is best when applying `On Error Resume Next`.

```vb
Sub detectIfAnOfficeAppIsOpen()
    
    Dim objWord As Object
    
    ' Bypass expected error
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    ' Remove error bypass as soon as possible
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Handle expected error
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Word.Application not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Word.Application found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Error can (mast) be cleared?

Comment: @ValNik The comment is unclear. `Debug.Print Err.Number` after `On Error GoTo 0` will be 0.

Comment: Unexpected for me, really ``on error goto 0`` clears error. Thank you.

Comment: Problem solved!  Many thanks to everyone for your assistance.